# Error in file name when creating a downloadable CSV file in PHP page according to some condition

Tags: php, csv

I want to create a .csv file(at a time) in a PHP page and download them. Here is my code -

**test.php**

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");

    $i = 5;

    if ([some condition]) {

        $fileName = "file_1.csv";

            while ( $i > 0 ) {
                echo "mail_id :: date". PHP_EOL;
                $i--;

            }
    }elseif ([some condition]){

        $fileName = "file_2.csv";

            while ( $i > 0 ) {
                echo "mail_id :: date". PHP_EOL;
                $i--;
            }
    }elseif ([some condition]){

            $fileName = "file_3.csv";

            while ( $i > 0 ) {
                echo "mail_id :: date". PHP_EOL;
                $i--;
            }
    }

        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
```

but as output of my code only

> file_1.csv

is downloaded correctly, and in case of others it is downloading a .csv file,but in different name (not in **file_2.csv** / **file_3.csv**). Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have `echo` before you send those headers. All headers need to be sent _before_ any other output.

Comment: why cant you save your file and download?

Comment: @Magnus Thank you very much. Now it's working.